# Layout Control within figures

Tags: floats

So I tried to make this (and succeeded):

[image]

It's a figure with two pieces of content (a table and a figure), each with elaborate layout within the picture. Both the table and figure are defined in a different file (set in standalone class), and included using `\includestandalone{}`.
Finally, the captions also have customized layout.

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\start{document}

text
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \hspace{-1 cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includestandalone{Table1}
        \hspace{1 cm}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{1.35\textwidth}
            \vspace{0.75cm}
            \centering
            Table 1 (Right): A table\\
            Figure 9 (Left): A schematic representation. 
            \setcounter{table}{1}
            \setcounter{figure}{9}
            \vspace{0.25cm} %0.75cm+0.25cm= 1cm
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{-5.2 cm}
    \par
    \raisebox{0pt}[5 cm]
        {\hspace{9.5 cm}\includestandalone{Figure9}}
\end{figure}
text
```

It works, but only after hours of messing around. I now have an ugly solution that I don't know how to even replicate next time I want something like this. In short, I still don't know how to effectively control layout within a figure. So that is my question: are there easy/consistent/effective/nonhacky ways to control layout  within a figure? How to make sense of this?

---

So you might say: well you just put the two next to one another and use `\vspace{}` and `\hspace` to position each next element where you want. If you want to go up and left, you just use negative numbers.
*But no, because these commands do not constistently work. Sometimes they do not work, and sometimes they give unexpected results (such as moving the entire figure up instead of just the part you want to move up.)*

So then you might think: Oh, well, you just put them in boxes and position the boxes, or position the content pieces inside the boxes. Surely some combination works. In fact `\minipage` even has a position handle to outline it at the boxes on top or on the bottom. Surely you can make use of that somehow.
*Well, only if you use two different box types. I've tried solutions using only `\minipage{}` for both and solutions using `\raisebox{}` for both content pieces, but alas, that didn't work. What does work is some combination between two different boxes, and who kows what combinations work?*

I have seen that LaTeX *really* wants to position the table's and figure's bottoms at the same height. Even `\minipages'` position handle doesn't really have what it takes to override this.

Comment: Which kind of position do you want to obtain? I mean, expressed in term of relative positions, and not just specific size. For example, in your figure above, which is the idea? Having one block consisitng ot the table with the two caption below it, and then the figure at the right and bottom aligned with the first block? Or something different?

Comment: Yea, you mean the difference between relatove and absolute positions.

Comment: Really, what I'd like to know is both. I'm a little frustrated with the fact that stuff I expected to be consistent is not as consistent as I thought. So any of the two tactics, if it works well, would be welcome to know.